# Size classes not reflecting when poping to view controller

Tags: ios, ipad, constraints, xib, size-classes

I have added `constraints` using size classes ,and used metrics Any-Any for all `iPhones` and for `iPad` I have used Regular-Regular.
I have designed one `UIView` on Xib using these size classes , and loading it in `viewDidLoad` using nib name . In `iPad`(Regular - Regular metrics) first time when view controller appears its taking correct size class but when i pop from other view controller to this view controller then size class is changed to Any-Any . I am not able to figure out the reason behind this change of size classes.

*Edited*

I have loaded my view like this .

```
defaultScreenView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(NIB_NAME_DEFAULT_SCREEN, owner: self, options: nil)[INT_CONSTANT_ZERO] as! DefaultScreenView
```

Comment: Can you please show the code for loading nib ?

Comment: I have loaded my view like this .                                            defaultScreenView =  NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(NIB_NAME_DEFAULT_SCREEN,
                                                                    owner: self, options: nil)[INT_CONSTANT_ZERO] as! DefaultScreenView